# is it possible to add camera object to RVIZ?

Tags: rviz, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to add a camera object ,which is attached to end-effector of a manipulator, to RVIZ. I want to subscribe images in a Node and process them. Is it possible? How?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201700/is-it-possible-to-add-camera-object-to-rviz?/) by [Javad](https://answers.ros.org/users/21473/javad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See: http://answers.ros.org/question/11028/rviz-camera-view/

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0